# Where is my Skype profile picture stored on OS X?

Tags: macos, graphics, skype

I took a profile picture for Skype using the "Capture a picture from a video camera" button found in the Skype profile dialog.  Now I want to use the picture for other things but I cannot find where the picture is being stored.  Any ideas?

(OS X Lion 10.7, Skype 5.3)

Comment: Actually this answer will also be useful for deleting the profile picture, since Skype does not seem to have a delete button once you enter a profile picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just tried this, and the answer was unexpected...

When I created the image it was stored in the following folder (before Mountain Lion):

```
~/Library/Images/IChat Recent Pictures
```

Please note that as per [skh's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/64397/172499), since Mountain Lion (and still valid for macOS Sierra) the images are now stored in the following folder:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Library/Images/Recent\ Pictures/
```

Comment: It could be that it saves it here for everyone, or maybe it is just saving it in the same place that the last captured picture was saved?

Comment: True, or it could be I'm using a different version of Skype possibly, or that my picture wasn't a picture from my iSight. Did you use your picture as your avatar?

Comment: @ioi I'm using OS X 10.7 and Skype 5.3 the same as in the question. I clicked "Change Picture" on my profile page in the Skype interface and used the video camera to create the picture.

Comment: I found it where you said it is ... so I've marked the answer as correct.

Comment: @ioi ... yep I used the picture as my avatar

Comment: I got a new mac with Mavericks preinstalled, and it's not true there. (guess since they stopped with iChat). That's why I downvoted

Answer (score 24):

Took me a while to find this, but here's the profile picture directory in Mountain Lion:

`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Library/Images/Recent\ Pictures/`

Comment: Confirmed in El Capitan

Comment: Confirmed in Sierra